# What is the best practice to pass many server side information to JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

Let say that I have many Javascript inside pages. At this moment is pretty easy to initialize variable by simply using some Print/Echo statement to initialize JavaScript value.

```
Example: var x = <?php echo('This is a value');?>
```

I first thought that I could pass all variables value by parameter of function BUT it's impossible because we have a lot of values (we have a multilanguage website and all text are from the server (BD)).

```
Example : initializeValues(<?php echo('Value1,Value2,Value3,Value...');?>);//JS Method that can be external of the page
```

More problem come when we want to take off all JavaScript from pages to move everything on **external** JavaScript file. What would be the good way to initialize all those variables? If I bind the JavaScript methods by using OnLoad of the document I won't be able to use Print/Echo method to populate all values.

Any good pattern to resolve this task?

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about the content of the variables? Are they just the translation labels? Do they change between requests? Or are they mostly static?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very popular pattern is the use of the JSON format. There are libraries to produce it, and Javascript directly consumes it.

Comment: +1 for JSON. It's simple, concise, easy to read and has libraries for nearly every language.

Answer (score 3):

With php you can create an associative array then using json_encode you can serialize it for output on the page between some script tags.

for some examples on doing that you can look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it:

```
<?php

$foo = array('bar' => 'gork');

?>
<input id='foo' type='hidden' value='<?= json_encode($foo); ?>' />
```

Then client side (I'm using Prototype) :

```
var foo = $F('foo').jsonParse();
alert(foo.bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = <?php echo('This is a value');?>
```

Er, no, that would end up as:

```
var x = This is a value
```

(syntax error.) You want:

```
var x = <?php echo json_encode('This is a value', JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_QUOT);?>
```

The HEX_TAG escaping in PHP 5.3 avoids problems with the `</` sequence appearing in a `<script>` block. The AMP and QUOT encoding is needed to ensure there are no problem `"` and `&` characters when you're putting code in an attribute value delimited by `"` or a non-CDATA XHTML script block. If you're only ever using a HTML script block (or XHTML CDATA script block) you can get away without them (although they do no harm either).

`json_encode` will also happily encode an array of values to put in a JS variable, not just a string.

```
More problem come when we want to take off all JavaScript from pages to move everything on external JavaScript file.
```

It's a good idea to put all your static code, including code that binds onto event listeners, in an external JavaScript file. However per-page data should still stay on the page, either in appropriate attributes of the document itself (eg. class names for unobtrusive scripting) or in a simple `<script type="text/javascript">var data= ...;</script>` block with no other code.

Answer (score -1):

best practice?  passing values from server to the client-side js is too volatile for a singular best practice.

let's say you use Smarty.  then, *my* best practice is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var limit = Number("{$limit}");
var msg = "{$msg}";

{literal}
// code using the variables
{/literal}
</script>
```

but I can also see this as a very sensible approach:

```
function to_js_vars(arrray $jsvars)
{
    foreach ($jsvars as $name => $info) {
        printf(
            "var %s = %s("%s");\n"
          , $name
          , $info['type']
          , $info['val']
        );
    }
}
```

where `$info['type']` is one of `Number`, `Boolean`, and `''` (empty string) for everything else